# Boost files differ in the /usr/local/include and /usr/include

Tags: c++, boost

I found that the boost files in `/usr/local/include differs` from the ones in `/usr/include`. e.g. in the `/usr/local/include/system/error_code.hpp`, a macro named `BOOST_NO_CXX11_HDR_SYSTEM_ERROR` is defined:

```
#ifndef BOOST_NO_CXX11_HDR_SYSTEM_ERROR
#include <system_error>
#endif
```

What is the use of this difference?

Comment: Why should different files not differ? What possible reasons have you ruled out?

Comment: If they were not different why would they be in different locations? What's your actual problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: /usr/local is local admins' responsibility. You need to ask them. No one else can possible have any idea what they have put there and why.

Answer (score 0):

You have simply installed competing/conflicting versions of boost on the same system.

In general, that's a bad idea. But in case you know what you're doing (and how) it can be useful to have different versions of Boost on the same system.

Do consider using some abstraction like Docker containers or LXC to isolate the different installations though. These methods exist to avoid unplanned interference with "other applications" on the system.